# What good libraries are there for solving a system of non-linear equations in C++?

Tags: c++, math, libraries, equation-solving

In a C++ application I'm coding, I need to solve a system of **non**-linear equations (N equations, N unknowns).

The systems I'm solving will be rather small (up to 10 equations/unknowns), so performance is not going to be a real issue.
I've searched the web a bit for a non-linear solver library, and I couldn't get to something which looks easy to use (got to *NOX* and [C/C++ Minpack](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/cminpack/cminpack.html), but both seem to be an overkill for my need).

Any thoughts and ideas of easy-to-use libraries for this purpose?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/51915/40286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options for you, you can use the sundials packages which includes a nonlinear solver, written in C I think. The only problem I've found with it is that you need to give it good initial estimates. The second option is to use NLEQ or NLEQ2 which I think are superior (writtein in FORTRAN but easy to link to  C like langages. However I have had some problems locating it just now.  There is a good web site with a list of possible options at: http://plato.asu.edu/sub/zero.html

Comment: Thanks. I've used the sundials package (KINSOL) and it works like a charm from a C++ program on Windows 64.

Comment: hi @hoffer, I am also very interested in solving nonlinear systems by Newton-type method. About the usage of NLEQ and NLEQ2, do you have any simple working example to show the implementations of the algorithm? Thanks

Comment: hi @rhody, how can I link NLEQ/NLEQ2 in Fortran to C++? I have visual C++ 9.0 Express in Win32 OS. Do I need any Fortran77 complier? thanks

Comment: You'll need a fortran compiler, probably g77 will work (I happened to use a commercial one). After than you'll need to access the Fortran through a C call not C++.

Answer (score 3):

One thing should be clear: non-linear equation solution isn't easy.  It's not the same as solving linear equations.  You aren't always guaranteed to get a solution.  And your choice of initial condition and incrementation strategy can have a profound effect on the solution you do get.

With that said, I can't recommend a particular library, but you should be on the lookout for a linear algebra package that includes Newton-Raphson iteration in its menu of choices.

Comment: The relevant section of Numerical Recipes is particularly clear on your first point.

Comment: For example, GSL.

Comment: For those not fluent in acronyms, GSL == GNU Scientific Library.  https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multidimensional-Root_002dFinding.html

Answer (score 1):

Numerical Recipes has a routine that will do the job for you.

Comment: A great source of code is netlib. Mostly it's FORTRAN but f2c will soon see to that.  Incidentally I'd say f2c is one of the great programs of all time!  I'd recommend Numerical Recipes as a great way to get good orientation in many areas of numerical analysis without needing to be an expert.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how non-linear the equations are. If they possess some "nice" properties...most obvious being positive-semi-definite matrix or convexity, there may be specialized algorithms available. I use IBM/ILOG CPLEX for most of my linear programming needs. Libraries are provided that can be pulled into C++ applications. Although I have not used their quadratic programming module, it is really the state-of-the-art in high horse-power linear and (well-behaved) non-linear programming.

Answer (score 1):

There is always GSL, but all the comments made in the other answers apply to this as well:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multidimensional-Root_002dFinding.html#index-nonlinear-systems-of-equations_002c-solution-of-2426

Comment: GSL Ch 38. [Non Linear Least-Squares Fitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html#Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [COIN-OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COIN-OR)?  It might help if you submit your question to the OR-Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free by any means, but [Solver](http://solver.com/equation-solver.htm) would work here.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Z3 https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp

also consider omnn::math:
https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/master/omnn/math/test/08_System.cpp

Lets say system of equations is like this:

```
(x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 = c1
(x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 = c2
```

Then you have couple options:

```
Valuable a1, a2, b1, b2; // init with values

System sys;
Variable x,y;
sys << (x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 - c1; // addin an equation as an equality to 0
sys << (x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 - c2;

for(auto& solution : sys.Solve(x))
        std::cout << solution;
```

alternative way is to make single equation (see [why](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHZU35q3m9k&index=6&list=PLnI9xbPdZUAmUL8htSl6vToPQRRN3hhFp)):

((x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 - c1)^2 + ((x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 - c2)^2 = 0

```
Variable x,y;
Valuable a1, a2, b1, b2; // init with values
auto eq = ((x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 - c1)^2 + ((x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 - c2)^2;
eq.SetView(Valuable::View::Equation);  // optional: equation optimizations
// get y function:
auto fn = eq(y);

// show
std::cout << fn << std::endl;

// evaluate
auto evaluate = fn;
evaluate.eval(x, 10);
evaluate.optimize(); // calculate
// show calculated value at x=10:
std::cout << evaluate << std::endl;
```