# C++ Newton-Raphson algo?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

I have a huge problem. I need to solve a non linear sistem of 3 equations in 3 variables with a C++ function or class. I thought about using Newton-Raphson method to perform the solution. Unlukily I didn't find a source code that can do that for me. There would be someone that knows a program like that? I'm near deciding to build it myself. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3x3 system is not huge; it's actually a very small problem.  People routinely solve nonlinear systems of equations with thousands (and more) of variables and constraints.

Given that your system is 3x3 and possibly nasty, a more appropriate choice of method would be a line search method.  You get global convergence to a local minimum of the residual this way; it's very easy to make straight Newton's method diverge.

Steepest descent with backtracking line search is the simplest line search method possible.  You might try implementing it first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've done an alghorithm NELDER-HELD, to find minimum or maximum of a function, it's very accurate could I use it to solve my problem?

Comment: @TommasoFerrari:  I'd never recommend using Nelder-Mead.  It might work fine for your problem, though; give it a shot if you've already got it written up.

Answer (score 1):

First, see related questions [What good libraries are there for solving a system of non-linear equations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233964/what-good-libraries-are-there-for-solving-a-system-of-non-linear-equations-in-c) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914967/could-you-explain-how-newton-raphson-for-a-set-of-equations-works-code-inside. Also, try to use [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/toolkit/internals1/roots.html).

Comment: hi @user1929959 does Boost have any algorithm for solving nonlinear systems? Where can I find the detailed documents? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider this [cozy C++ library](https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/77d79f62ded371579ed2812850b81a9f30d2693e/omnn/math/test/08_System.cpp#L67)